# solving definite integral problems without complex line integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

It is well known that some definite integrals such as
$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{dx}{a+\cos{x}}$$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin{x}}{x}dx$$
are solved by using complex analysis techniques. (It uses residue theorem.)

But some of them are proved by only substitution like Harish Chandra Rajpoot answer.
$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \log(\sin{x}) dx =-\pi\log{2}$$
(See [definite integral without using complex line integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391822/definite-integral-without-using-complex-line-integral))

Are there any definite integral problems those cannot be soloved without complex line integral tecniques?

Comment: No, but there might be easier solutions than using complex line integral techniques.

Comment: I'm interested, in which sense your first integral converges?

Comment: And yes there are example  where i'm quite confident that the only way to get a solution is by complex integration techniques, see here for more information: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253910/the-integral-that-stumped-feynman

Comment: @this_is_an_apple The first integral can be done without residues. It can be done with High School Calculus, provided that a>1 because otherwise the integral is divergent (denom has zeros) And that upper limit should not be infinity, perhaps it could be 2pi?

Comment: Another very hard nut to crack without some form of complex analysis may be http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200613/why-does-int-0-infty-frac-ln-1x-ln2-x-pi2-fracdxx2-give-t

Comment: Your first integral is infinite as written.  Do you mean the integration interval to be between $[0,2 \pi]$.